# Clean up [untagged] questions

Tags: discussion, tags, clean-up

This is a clean-up task which'll never end.

There is a regular job that removes tags that are only on 1 (or fewer) questions. What this means is that any question with one of these "orphan" tags suddenly has no tags, so the system applies the pseudo-tag [untagged](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) to it. This makes it hard to discover the questions.

Here are ways to help with this clean-up effort:

1. First and foremost, tag the question with the tag for the web application to which it is referring. (If it's not referring to a specific web app, it may be too broad and not on-topic here.) If it's for a web application but the tag doesn't exist, see if there are other questions for that web app. If so, the tag should be created.
2. To keep a tag around even if it's only on one question, be sure that it has a tag wiki excerpt (including guidance on when to use the tag here) as well as a description.
3. If it's otherwise a good question, but needs editing, do so! If people are finding questions about a web app here, they'll ask more questions about it, then it won't be difficult to keep an appropriate tag.
4. Even better, if you find an untagged question that you can answer, do it!
5. If a question is off-topic here (too broad, about programming, etc.) vote to close, and, if appropriate, vote to delete.

Answer (score 4):

I've picked through the remaining 9 questions, and it seems like they are largely in the realm of esoteric sites.

I'm inclined to leave them here, since they are about legitimate web apps, just not ones with a large enough following to justify a tag.

Comment: I would tend to agree. I wonder why some of them haven't been auto-deleted, though.