# Was the tag "Upwork" removed, and if so, why?

Tags: discussion, tags

I saw that the question [Why can't I see some of the job postings of some members of my Upwork team?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/154431/18147) is untagged. I'm guessing it used to have the [upwork](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upwork) tag but I could be wrong. Was the tag "Upwork" removed, and if so, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tags having only one question that either haven't tag excerpt / wiki are automatically removed. This is a standard feature of SE and already discussed in Meta SE -> [What causes a question to be tagged as [untagged]?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167879/289691)

Users having enough rep can add the tag again. It might be worthy that tag wiki be added to prevent the tag to be automatically removed again.

Related

- [Clean up [untagged] questions](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4152/88163)

Comment: Thanks for the information!